# Cannot login to Xen guest pv

Tags: xen

I've followed this [guide](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Beginners_Guide#Creating_a_Debian_PV_.28Paravirtualized.29_Guest) to setup a Xen server and my first PV Guest.  On the host system I only have two users, root and benny.  I usually work through benny.

After creating a .cfg for my new pv guest, foobar-server, I run the following command:

```
benny@romulus:~$ sudo xm create -c /etc/xen/foobar-server.cfg
```

This initiates a boot-up process and after a minute or so drops me at a login prompt:

> Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 foobar-server hvc0
>
> foobar-server login:

I have tried logging in as root (no password), root (with password for host box), benny (with password); none of which have had any success.  I have no idea how to login to my new vm.  Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: I also face this problem,I create vm by myself. But I don't know the username

Answer (score 2):

When you installed your new VM, you should have set up a new user/root password.  The login information for your guest (domU) is almost certainly not the same as the login information for the host (dom0).  So, if you downloaded an image, there should be some documentation for that image that tells you what login info to use.  If you installed from an install source (HTTP/FTP/ISO/etc.), you should have set it during install time.

If you need to force it to change, you can insert the following into the config file and do the create, again:
extra="init=/bin/bash"

This will boot you straight to a bash prompt, and you should be able to use passwd to change the root password.  Then shut it down, remove that line from the config file, and do the create, again, and try to log in as root.  Some more recent distributions (notably Ubuntu) actually do not allow/set a root password by default, so you might have to actually do that and set the password to log in under the root account.

Comment: I create vm by myself, but I don't find the place where I set the username, I do know the password from the log after compiling the vm.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Xen and met the same problem. I used xen-tools to build the Xen guest and tackled the problem with an original method:

1. delete the original guest first, with the command `xen-delete-image`,
2. then build the new guest using the command `xen-create-image` with the parameter `--password="<your root password>"`.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying. Can you please [edit] this and try to make it clearer?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. The main idea is that you should add the "--password" parameter when building the guest with xen-create-image, and this password will be your root password. I did not create another user but only the root user.